# "He lost the game to his rival but he was only complimentary."

Tags: word-usage

What is the function of *only* in this sentence?

> He lost the game to his rival but he was **only** complimentary.

Answer (score 1):

*Only* is an adverb. It is a complement of the adjective *complimentary*. After losing a game, some people may be angry or spiteful at the winner. But not that person: he congratulated the winner, he was nice with the winner: he was *complimentary*. No other word is necessary to qualify his behavior, for example the compliments were not insincere: he was *only* complimentary. The word *only* puts some emphasis on the complimentary behavior.

Comment: Surely you mean it modifies *complimentary*? A *complement* to *complimentary* would be something like *of his rival's performance*.

Comment: So it's an emphasis...like "I'm only too happy to help you."?

Comment: @kih1930 No, it's excluding all other possibilities: he wasn't rude, he wasn't resentful, etc. He was *only* complimentary (or *just* complimentary). Ex. "He only dates redheads." He does not date blondes or brunettes; he *just* dates redheads.

Comment: I would say it's both, in a way. By excluding other possibilities (such as showing resentment or anger), it's an indirect way of emphasizing his graciousness.